# multidimensional array and jaggered array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
r[k] = new double[3, 3] { { 1 ,0 ,-T * MPCV[k] * (Math.Sin(A[k])) },
                                  { 1 ,0 , T * MPCV[k] * (Math.Cos(A[k])) },
                                  { 0 ,0 ,1}
                                };
```

I shall rephrase my question. Am i declaring correctly if i were to set a 3x3 matrix within an array of 5 elements as my k will run from 5 to 1.

Comment: Can you post code that will actually compile? What is this? `double [][,] = new double [5][,]`. Arrays don't have column names, either, so could you show us the exact error you're getting, and the line?

Comment: is it a typo or you are missing the naming of the array at the declaration?

Answer (score 1):

> "if i were to set a 3x3 matrix within an array of 5 elements as my k
>   will run from 5 to 1"

If your array is of 5 elements, you cannot run `k` from 5 to 1. The **index** in C# **starts from 0** (**unlike** MATLAB, for example, which starts from 1). You can only run `k` from 4 to 0.

Thus, be careful of your `A` `MPCV` and `r`. Because when `k` is `5` all of them may get error.

If `r` is not fixed size or is not to be computed as array (but merely as a List of matrices), I also suggest that your `r` variable to use `List` instead of array. Simply declare it like this

```
List<double[,]> r = new List<double[,]>() {
    new double[3, 3], new double[3, 3], new double[3, 3], new double[3, 3], new double[3, 3]
};
```

Then just use it like what you do:

```
r[k] = new double[3, 3] { 
  { 1, 0, -T * MPCV[k] * (Math.Sin(A[k])) },
  { 1, 0,  T * MPCV[k] * (Math.Cos(A[k])) },
  { 0, 0, 1}
};
```

As long as your `k` is between 0 to 4 (inclusive), then it should be find.